# Application to suggest Hearthstone decks?

Tags: web-apps, game

For the Blizzard card game Hearthstone, there are sites such as Hearthpwn that list cards, and allow users to show off their decks/builds and rate others. I'm looking for a similar application that would allow you to enter the cards you have, and it would tell you the decks (from the user submissions, ranked by popularity) you can build with the cards you have available. I'd want to order the list by similarity (how many cards you have vs. how many cards you still need) and popularity (of the deck on Hearthpwn).

Requirements:

- Allows card collection to be entered
- Allows deck building, and voting on those decks
- Shows difference between your collection and a given deck in dust value and list of cards missing

Nice to have:

- Full card data/descriptions (i.e. not just the name)
- Has established database of popular decks

Comment: I haven't heard of such a thing, and I wouldn't have thought to look for one, but now that you suggest the possibility, I'd love to have this, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know I commented that I hadn't heard of such a thing, but just tonight I accidentally found what you're looking for.

WoWhead, as part of their Hearthstone site ([Hearthhead](http://www.hearthhead.com)), has a tool where you can enter your current collection, then apply that as a filter to all decks that people have submitted.

It has a deck-building tool, with up and down voting, your crafting cost to complete that deck (but as far as I can tell, *not* a list of what you need to craft), and so on.

[image]

It has full card data in the tooltip of every card, complete with how many of them you own, and 28964 constructed decks submitted as of right now. I can't speak to their overall quality, but there are definitely good ones in there, and there's a lot of filters you can apply to find one that works for you.

Comment: This has the functionality of the most important feature, so thanks!

Comment: @bd33 - You're welcome!  And if you do figure out how to get a list of "Craft this to complete the deck", please leave a comment and I'll edit it in.